# How to take specific rows from postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, limit, rows, sql-limit

If I need select 20 to 30 rows from PostgreSQL, how can I retrieve that ?

```
SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 10
```

This is fetching top 10 rows only. Can we do this in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Specify `OFFSET` in addition to `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

You may want to use the `ORDER BY` clause as well as by default the rows are returned in an unspecified order.

See [LIMIT and OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-limit.html) in the PostgreSQL docs.

Answer (score 0):

OFFSET actually just says how many rows to skip before beginning to return rows which in this case are limited to 10 rows. You just want to change the number of rows you are limiting to:

```
    select column from table limit 20;
```

or

```
    select column from table limit 30;
```